Big-O notation: how do I prove (or disprove) the $\cos(x)/x = O(1)$?
So, here I'm kinda stuck with this one since I have troubles with understanding the Big-O notation at all, so I'd like to get any useful tips or explanations.
So, what I know is the Big-O definition and I've tried to solve this task using the definition.
$f \in O(g) \Rightarrow \exists \; \left.x_0, c \in \mathbb{N} \;\right| \; \forall \ x > x_0 \;: \; |f(x)| \leq c \cdot |g(x)|$
Hence, $\exists \; \left. x_0, c \; \right| \; \frac{\cos x}{x} \leq c \cdot 1, \; \forall \ x > x_0 \Rightarrow \exists \; \left. x > c \; \right| \; x = c + 1 + x_0$
And I'm not quite sure in the last statement since making $x = c + 1 + x_0$ doesn't help as much, as I firstly thought. Also I have an idea that we possibly might use that $\cos(x) = [-1, 1]$ anyway, yet I haven't figured out yet how exactly this could helped in this task.

Just a little nuance : You want $|f(x)|\le c|g(x)|$ since $f$ is not strictly positive.

Your implication arrows are in the opposite direction from what you need. Moving the $\forall$ from the middle of the formula to the end is a bad move, since it makes it ambiguous whether the $\forall$ or $\exists$ applies first. Since you rely so heavily on symbols to say what you mean, it’s hard to tell whether you’re confused in your thoughts or just confused about notation.

I am assuming you are considering $x\to+\infty$. In that case, just notice that, for $x>1$ you have $1/|x|<1$ and, since $|\cos x|<1$ you have $|\cos x/x|<1$, so you can choose $c=1$ and $x_0=1$.

Beware, $\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac {cos(x)} x = 0$, so it is not a $O(1)$ but a $o(1)$. In fact it is a $O(\frac 1 x)$...

@Serge I think you are mistaken $O(1)$ and $\Theta(1)$. Being $O(f(x))$ means $\le c|f(x)|$ therefore $O(1)$ just means bounded. And something that goes to $0$ is indeed bounded. Sure it is imprecise compared to $o(1)$ but not wrong.

@DavidK  Thanks. Sure, this is a better wording for the answer. Of course any bigger $c$ works, and a larger $x_0$ also. I will change the wording for clarity.

That looks good.

@zwim: I think I am now a bit old... When I was a student (in France), I only know the $o$ and $O$. And my teacher used $O$ in the sense of $\Theta$. But wikipedia makes clear that I was wrong and you are right ;-)
